# Does MSOLAP.5 automatically ship when the Power Pivot addin is installed

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

We have been getting the following error on some user's PCs when they are trying to connect to `Analysis Services OLAP cubes`:

> XML for Analysis parser: The restriction value provided by the
>   consumer either does not match other restrictions or refers to an
>   unknown object

This details the problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5bf0ecce-1561-4e05-ae26-fce19cf1aa91/xml-for-analysis-parser-the-restriction-value-sql-server-2005-with-excel-2010-error?forum=sqlanalysisservices

Would asking the user to install the `Power Pivot` add-in solve the problem? i.e. when downloading this add-in is the latest version of `MSOLAP` included in the download ?

Comment: Just get it from MS - [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35580)

Comment: @Raystafarian that link is to the download page for "Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 SP1 Feature Pack" ....I want a user to be able to run Anal Services from their PC: do you have a link to a more specific page?